# How can I change the value of the cells in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel sheet with numbers. Most of the numbers formatted as scientific numbers with the symbol E              (e.g:10E-8, 1E-6, 0.235, 234E-10...).
I want to format them, for example, with 4.01E-10
,10E-7,235E-3,0.234E-9, 1.61E-09
.
so I think I should manipulate each number in each cell. how can I do that?
should I reference them in the data source or inside the pivot table

so far:

```
Dim PvtRng As Range, C As Range

Set PvtRng = pvt.DataBodyRange ' <-- set the Pivot Data range

For Each C In PvtRng ' loop cell by cell inside the Pivot-Table's DataBodyRange
    C.NumberFormat = " 0.00#" & "E-3"
Next C
```

Please suggest how to do this with vba.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `PvtRng.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00"` to put the cells in scientific notation. No need for a loop, unless you are trying to impose different formats on different cells for some reason, in which case you need to work out (and specify) the logic for that decision.

Comment: the pvtrng.numberformat ="0.00E+00" make the  number as a scientific number format only and it dose not controol the "E+00".Sometimes it E-07 and Sometimes E-08.   yes , i am trying to impose different formats on different cells. for example: i have numbers the should be  Within certain limits.

Comment: @ofir I don't think what you want is within the scope of formatting then. The scientific format can't be adjusted like that.

Comment: 100E-9 is an invalid scientific notation and if you use it at any professional level then you will make yourself look foolish